# JSP compilation and Weblogic 10.3.4

Tags: java, jsp, ant, oracle11g, weblogic-10.x

We are in the process of upgrading from BEA Weblogic and ALSB to Oracle Weblogic and OSB 10.3.4. One of the things that are failing is our ant task for compiling jsp pages for our WAR.

This is the part of the ant build file that is failing now:

```
<!-- Compile the JSP files -->
        <path id="workshop.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${env.WL_HOME}/workshop/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/tools/eclipse_pkgs/1.1/pkgs/eclipse/plugins/com.bea.workshop.wls.ant_1.0.20.200802230117/workshop-wls-antlib.jar"/>
        </path>
        <taskdef 
name="jspc"
classname="com.bea.workshop.wls.antlib.tasks.JspcTask" classpathref="workshop.classpath"/>
        <path id="jspc.classpath">
            <path refid="java.classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/jdk150_11/lib/tools.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${env.WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />
       </path>
        <jspc source="@{war.staging.dir}" classpathref="jspc.classpath" failonerror="true" />
```

It cannot resolve the jar file with JspcTask since Workshop does not exist in 10.3.4. So the question is, how should this ant script be changed to work under 10.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

The `taskdef` with the `classname` below works with WLS 10.3.3

```
<taskdef name="jspc" 
classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Jspc" classpath="{ORACLE_MIDDLEWARE_HOME}\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar"> 
</taskdef>
```

Check your `weblogic.jar` with winzip/winrar to see if the above `classname` exists in 10.3.4, and it should be fine.

Update:

You're getting the NullPointer because `jspc` does not allow a directory in the `source` attribute. It should be `srcdir` [as per the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html), in fact I dont see a `source` attribute at all.

The `jspc` task is deprecated, so I think it's better you use the `weblogic.appc` like below

```
<target name="compileapp">
<java classname="weblogic.appc" fork="yes">
<arg line="-webapp ${src.gui}" />
<arg value="-compiler javac" />
<arg line="-classpath D:\Oracle\Middleware_Jdev11_1_1_4\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar" />
<arg value="-depend" />
<arg value="-nowarn" />
</java>
</target>
```

Choose the attributes you want [from this list](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb/appc_ejbc.html), I havent tried this myself yet.

Comment: OK, thanks! It now looks like this: `code`<taskdef name="jspc" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Jspc" classpath="${env.WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar"></taskdef>
        <path id="jspc.classpath">
            <path refid="java.classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${env.WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />
       </path>
        <jspc src="@{war.staging.dir}" classpathref="jspc.classpath" />`code` I now get a null pointer exception in the line with the jspc invocation. Am I missing some arguments perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot get code formatting work in the comments. Here is the line invoking jspc in isolation: `code`<jspc src="@{war.staging.dir}" classpathref="jspc.classpath" />`code`

Comment: @user432291: yes, your NullPointer is because the `jspc` does *not* allow a directory in `src` attribute.

Comment: This is the solution we ended up with: `code`<path id="appc.classpath">    
    <path refid="java.classpath"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${env.WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />        
  </path>
  
        <wlappc source="@{war.staging.dir}" classpathref="appc.classpath" verbose="true"/>`code` Thank you for the help JoseK, it is much appreciated